# How to run a temporal query on a CSW using GeoNetwork?

Tags: cql-filter, geonetwork, time, csw

On my GeoNetwork 2.10.3 a CSW GetRecords request (CQL) for TempExtent_begin after a certain date returns all of my metadata records. It seems like the filter expression is simply ignored.

```
http://myserver:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw?SERVICE=CSW&version=2.0.2
&REQUEST=GetRecords&resultType=results
&constraintLanguage=CQL_TEXT&constraint_language_version=1.1.0
&constraint=TempExtent_begin%20after%202014-10-12T00:00:00Z
&elementSetName=full&outputSchema=http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd
```

Is this a problem of GeoNetwork or is there something wrong with my request?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for reply. I didn't know this log file. Really a great help!

Here is the solution for my problem:

```
http://myserver:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw?SERVICE=CSW&version=2.0.2
&REQUEST=GetRecords&resultType=results
&constraintLanguage=CQL_TEXT&constraint_language_version=1.1.0
&constraint=TempExtent_begin%20>=%20'2014-10-12T00:00:00Z'
&elementSetName=full&outputSchema=http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd
```

Operations AFTER and BEFORE are not supported. You have to use <= and >= instead. Furthermore you have to quote the <DateTime>.

Comment: When you are not sure where the log of an app is, try the catalina.out log directly on tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

If I try your request on the latest version of geonetwork, this is what the console output shows:

014-10-15 08:11:30,577 INFO  [jeeves.service] - Dispatching : csw
2014-10-15 08:11:30,580 INFO  [jeeves.webapp.csw] - Received:

  full
  1.1.0
  http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd
  CSW
  TempExtent_begin after 2014-10-12T00:00:00Z
  results
  CQL_TEXT
  GetRecords
  2.0.2

2014-10-15 08:11:30,581 INFO  [jeeves.webapp.csw] - Dispatching operation : GetRecords
oct 15, 2014 8:11:34 AM org.geotools.xml.impl.ParserHandler error
**ADVERTENCIA: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'ogc:Filter' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":spatialOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":comparisonOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":logicOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":_Id}' is expected.**

So your spatial filter seems to be incomplete or wrong.